# When using Nonmetric Multidimensional Scaling, is there an explanatory metric similar to loadings in PCA?

Tags: pca, multidimensional-scaling

As a beginner to MDS, here is my thought process:

Given a data set of environmental factors that may effect a certain sites, when I run a PCA on each site I get a list of principal components. If I want to understand which environmental factors are driving each of the principal components, ie:

```
PCA1 <- Mostly Oxygen and Salinity driven
PCA2 <- Mostly Temperature driven
```

I look at the loadings of the PCA results to find out which of the original environmental factors are weighting each of the principal components.

When I run a NMMDS on a similar set of data, my result is a plot in which the sites are grouped so that more dissimilar sites are further apart. While I can make an educated guess as to what is causing the grouping in an MSD plot, is there something analogous to the loadings of a PCA that explains which environmental variables may be playing the largest roles in the resulting plot? Or a way to quantify the input of each environmental variable to the final structure of the plot?

Comment: Loadings are (regressional) weights of components on variables, not of variables on components.

Comment: Please, tell more about how your data look. E.g.: when you do PCA on columns of data, what define rows and what define are columns? When you do MDS, what define you dissimilarity matrix and what dissimilarity you use?

Comment: I don't have any specific answers for my data yet, still in the nascent stages. This is more a general question to get an idea of what is possible with NMDS, and will I be able to quantify some of the visual results I see in my NMDS plots